# Ecs command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I am using Amazon Linux AMI Ec2 instance.When I try to deploy task getting error like ecs not found

```
bash-4.2$ ecs deploy demo-cluster demo-service
bash: ecs: command not found
```

When I try to start ecs its already running

```
[ec2-user@ip-152-31-44-88 ~]$ sudo start ecs
start: Job is already running: ecs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no such command installed on ECS ready AMIs.

Some observations regarding your question:

1. The ecs service you see running is the **Amazon ECS Container Agent.** This is a system level service, not a command line cli. See https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent.
2. Yes the AWS CLI is installed, but it is called via the `aws` command, not the  `ecs` command.
3. There is a AWS supported ecs cli, but it is invoked with the  `ecs-cli`  command, and has no deployment option. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CLI_reference.html
4. The only tool that I found that supports the command   `ecs deploy` is a 3rd party tool on GitHub. See https://github.com/fabfuel/ecs-deploy. As this is a 3rd party tool, you need to nstall it on the instance or on your local computer.

Comment: 4th point is exactly correct what I am looking for.From jenkins Still getting same error but If I try from command prompt ERROR: (service demo-service) was unable to place a task because no container instance met all of its requirements. The closest matching (container-instance ba93b620-89fa-4970-bf54-535a373d1abb) has insufficient CPU units available. For more information, see the Troubleshooting section of the Amazon ECS Developer Guide.

Comment: Ok. Kindly up vote and accept the answer here, and then open a new question and I can try to help you there.

Comment: From command prompt ecs commands are working but when I try from Jenkins getting ecs command not found. I need to install any plugin in Jenkins for this third party tool(ecs-deploy).

Comment: The user Jenkins runs under does not have a path to the executable.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to configure

Comment: Sure. Kindly open another question and link to it in the comments here.

Comment: can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60044044/jenkins-ecs-command-not-found

Comment: can you please help me