# Jenkins ecs Command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I installed third party tool (ecs deploy using `pip install ecs-deploy`) .When I try to deploy using command `ecs deploy demo-cluster demo-service` in command prompt its working fine when I try with jenkins to deploy getting error

```
/tmp/jenkins5062380414579854312.sh: line 13: ecs: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Can you confirm the full path for the `ecs` executable?

Comment: @RodrigoM I tried with whereis ecs command output : ecs: /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/ecs

Comment: @RodrigoM when I try with jenkins user whereis ecs not getting any output

Comment: Try this: in Jenkins call the command with the full path:  `/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/ecs deploy demo-cluster demo-service`. Ensure that the file can be read by Jenkins user.

Comment: @RodrigoM when I try with full path `bash-4.2$ /home/ec2-user/.local/bin/ecs deploy demo-cluster demo-service
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/bin/ecs", line 5, in <module>
    from ecs_deploy.cli import ecs
ImportError: No module named ecs_deploy.cli`

Comment: Can you do a `su - jenkins` and install via pip there? The issue is that you installed only for the `ec2-user` and jenkins user does not see the install.

Comment: @RodrigoM When I try `su - jenkins` its asking for password so I set the password using command `sudo passwd jenkins`.After setting when I try `su - jenkins` getting `jenkins is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.`

Comment: @RodrigoM When I installed ecs-deploy in ec2-user jenkins is not able to find ecs so I installed ecs-deploy in Jenkins user and set the path now I am able to deploy. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Great news!  If this was helpful, kindly upvote and accept my answer below. Please let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: @RodrigoM After deploying I am trying to access resource present in container but getting refused to connect. Question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101541/aws-cluster-not-able-to-access-resource-present-in-container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jenkins service runs typically runs under the user `jenkins`.

You have installed the package as the `ec2-user`.  This means the `jenkins` user may not have the package in its own path or have correct permissions to execute the file.

You can correct this one of two ways:

1. Use `sudo` to elevate permissions and install it globally. Set the path in `/etc/environment`
2. Interactively login as the `jenkins` user and install under that account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the full [AWS CLI command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/deploy/index.html):

```
aws ecs deploy --cluster demo-cluster --service demo-service
```

Comment: When I try with aws ecs deploy demo-cluster demo-service  getting error  aws: error: argument subcommand: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

Comment: can you please help me with this

Comment: I updated the command, looks like the syntax has changed in aws cli.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am using thrid party tool to deploy.Just check this once https://github.com/fabfuel/ecs-deploy