# AWS cluster not able to access resource present in container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I just created a cluster,task definition and a service.Container is running successfully but not able to access resource present in container.I am trying to access with Public DNS ipv4 getting

```
This site can’t be reached ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com 
refused to connect
```

[image: cluster]
[image: task]
[image: service]
[image: security group of an ec2instance where container is running]

Comment: The instance security group is not allowing ICMP protocol, which `ping` uses.  Please review https://serverfault.com/questions/511738/why-cant-i-ping-my-freshly-set-up-amazon-web-service-ec2-instance

Comment: @RodrigoM I tried with the steps present in link still not able to access.

Comment: @RodrigoM I tried by giving all traffic in inbound rules still same

Comment: @RodrigoM I deleted cluster,task,service and created again still not able to access

Comment: what ports are exposed from the container ? Do you define some port mapping in the  task definition already ?